# What is the proper way of adding search function to a viewmodel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I am trying to add a search functionality to a method where I can search a user by name. I have so far tried this but I am getting an error that I do not fully understand:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ListUsers(string searchString)
{
    var AllUsers = _application.Users.ToList();
    UsersAndRolesViewModel UserAndRoleViewModel = new UsersAndRolesViewModel();
    List<UserAndRoleViewModel> AllUsersAndRoles = new List<UserAndRoleViewModel>();

    foreach (var usr in AllUsers)
    {
        var model = new UserAndRoleViewModel
        {
            Id = usr.Id,
            Email = usr.Email,
            Roles = await _usermanager.GetRolesAsync(usr),
            PhoneNumber = usr.PhoneNumber,

        };

        AllUsersAndRoles.Add(model);
    }

    UserAndRoleViewModel.UserAndRole = AllUsersAndRoles;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
     UserAndRoleViewModel = AllUsers.Where(s => s.FullName.Contains(searchString));
    }


    return View(UserAndRoleViewModel);
}
```

The error this is producing is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ims.Models.ApplicationUser>`' to 'ims.Models.AdminViewModels.UsersAndRolesViewModel'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

This error is produced on

```
UserAndRoleViewModel = AllUsers.Where(s => s.FullName.Contains(searchString));
```

Comment: AllUsers.Where(...) returns an IEnumerable<Sometype> where Sometype is the type of your _application.Users variable. You try to assign that to a variable of type 'UsersAndRolesViewModel' and the compiler complains that it doesn't know how to do that since they're not the same type.

Comment: But what is the correct way to do that then? Because when trying to assign UserAndRoleViewModel  instead of AllUsers, the method fails complaining that usersandroleviewmodel doesnt contain a definition for Where. its treating Where as an entity?

Answer (score 0):

This is just caused by a fundamental type mismatch: `UserAndRoleViewModel` is of type `UsersAndRolesViewModel`. `AllUsers.Where(...)` is of type `IEnumerable<>`. I suspect you want to assign the result to a property of `UserAndRoleViewModel`.

Comment: But what is the correct way to do that then? Because when trying to assign UserAndRoleViewModel  instead of AllUsers, the method fails complaining that usersandroleviewmodel doesnt contain a definition for Where. its treating Where as an entity?

Comment: The correct way to do what? What do you want to achieve? Fundamentally, you cannot assign a value to a variable of a different type.

Comment: I want to achieve a functioning search feature in that controller, im not sure what i should be changing if this method doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to return a list of users to the View, try this

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
 List<UserAndRoleViewModel > UserRoles = AllUsers.Where(s => s.FullName.Contains(searchString)).ToList();
}
```

Or if you want to return a single user with particular name, try below

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
 var UserRoles = AllUsers.SingleOrDefault(s => s.FullName == searchString);
}
```

> AllUsers.Where(s => s.FullName.Contains(searchString))

returns a list of users. But you assigned it to a model.